# Integral domain on two lines

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

Consider the following integral:

```
$$\int_{\text{One line \\ Second line}} \text{Loss}\left(\text{Foo, Bar} \vert \alpha\right)$$
```

which renders:

[image]

How can I have `One line` and `Second line` on two separate and consecutive lines at the bottom of the integral?

Comment: amsmath `\substack` command

Comment: Consider also using `\[…\]` or `\begin{align*}…\end{align*}` rather than `$$`. Source : http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/34551

Comment: @Clément just FYI, I know you had good intentions with your suggested edit, but I rejected it because the answer likely has the `$$` only because the OP had the `$$`. Your comment here will hopefully help the OP to learn about the differences, and this will be sufficient because the post is a duplicate anyway. In general, when I think an answer should be changed, I simply leave a comment below it and let the author decide. Cheers!

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for explaining that decision, which is perfectly sensible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\substack` or `\subarray` from `amsmath`.  With `\subarray` you can control the justification.

```
\[ \int_{\substack{\text{One line} \\ \text{Second line}}}
\text{Loss}\left(\text{Foo, Bar} \vert \alpha\right) \]

\[ \int_{\begin{subarray}{l}\text{One line} \\ \text{Second line} \end
{subarray}} \text{Loss}\left(\text{Foo, Bar} \vert \alpha\right) \]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?lq=1, as well as @Clement already noted about the usage of `$$....$$`